# efficient/terse check for beginning/end of variable-content

Tags: string, bash

i'd like to implement a simplistic check whether the value of a string-variable has been user-supplied or generated.

the "algorithm" so far is to simply append/prepend a 'GUARD' value to the string if it is generated. something like:

```
 USERVAL=$1
 GUARDEDVAL=GUARD_${USERVAL}_GUARD
```

now i'm looking for a simple check to see whether the value of a variable has these GUARDS set. e.g. something like:

```
 check_guard() {
   local v=$1
   if [ "${v}" = "${v#GUARD_}" ]; then return 1; fi ## missing leading 'GUARD_'
   if [ "${v}" = "${v%_GUARD}" ]; then return 1; fi ## missing trailing 'GUARD_'
   return 0
 }
 check_guard "${GUARDEDVAL}" && echo "ok"
 check_guard "${USERVAL}"    && echo "ok"
```

now the implementation of `check_guard` works fine, but i think it is a bit verbose.

my question is: *can i somehow do the check for the presence of a string on both ends of a value?*

something like this (obviously non-working):

```
test "${v}" != "${${v#GUARD_}%_GUARD}"
```

i'd rather only use bash builtins and no external commands, like sed, as in

```
test "${v}" = "GUARD$(echo $v | sed -e 's|GUARD||g')GUARD"
```

the reason for all those hoops is, that the GUARDEDVAL really is the name of a lvm-partition which i create and destroy during the script, and i'd rather not destroy one of the other (e.g. used) disk-partitions in this process by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my question is: *can i somehow do the check for the presence of a
>   string on both ends of a value?*

One way would be to say:

```
[[ $VAL == ${GUARD}*${GUARD} ]] && echo ok
```

Comment: Or POSIX portably `case $VAL in "$GUARD"*"$GUARD" ) echo ok ;; esac`

Answer (score 2):

@devnull has the right idea. To turn it into a function:

```
$ check_guard() { [[ $1 == GUARD_*_GUARD ]]; }

$ check_guard foo && echo OK || echo BAD
BAD
$ check_guard GUARD_foo && echo OK || echo BAD
BAD
$ check_guard foo_GUARD && echo OK || echo BAD
BAD
$ check_guard GUARD_foo_GUARD && echo OK || echo BAD
OK
```

If you want case insensitivity:

```
$ check_guard() { local -u v=$1; [[ $v == GUARD_*_GUARD ]]; }

$ check_guard GUARD_foo_GUARD && echo OK || echo BAD
OK
$ check_guard guard_foo_GUARD && echo OK || echo BAD
OK
```